# Switching app with physical keyboard, with one click "alt + tab"

Tags: external-keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts

I love android's exensive support for keyboard, even "app switching" works almost exactly as in Windows/Mac OS/Some graphical Linux disitros.

When you click "alt+tab" it shows:

[image: Swiching app monit]

But what bothers me is that after you click "alt + tab" this window shows "actual app I used before"   so you need to click

"Alt + tab, and then keeping alt pressed again tab"  So those are 3 cliks instead of 2.

Is it customiazable ? Maybe I'm able change this behaviour?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just for clarification: Isn't this the way it's supposed to? Press (and hold) the ALT key, and then (repeatedly) using the TAB key until the wanted app is hilighted, then finally releasing the ALT key? At least that's how it works on the desktop.

Comment: @Izzy No. On the desktop when you click "alt + tab" and release you will switch the app. On Android when you do the same you end up in the same app. You have to click "alt + tab, and keeping tab pressed, click tab again and then release it. -> On Desktop 2 kepresses, on Android 3 presses to do the same thing.

Comment: How about just single-touch app switching? [Switchr](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mohammad.adib.switchr&hl=en) works great! I love having it on my tablet.

Answer (score 1):

the only way this works is as follows:

alt-tab, use arrows keys to select app and than press enter, once app has switched only than release alt-tab.

Hope this helps.